# Settings & widget import not working for Wordpress hosted on AWS Linux AMI

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I have a Wordpress site that I am hosting with an AWS micro instance. I purchased a template that requires me to import settings and widgets. I keep getting errors when I use the Wordpress settings import add-on.

I have tried looking at :

- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-widget-settings-importerexporter-import-doesnt-work
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content
- http://forum.bytesforall.com/showthread.php?t=18522

with no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem - and when setting up your machine image check that you installed php-xml. Wordpress importer uses xml to bring in the settings. Here is a link to the tutorial I followed -

[blog-tutorial](http://www.alexkorn.com/blog/2011/03/getting-php-mysql-running-amazon-ec2/)

And here is the specific line to install php-xml used -

```
sudo yum install php-xml
```